# Why does CPython has both C and .python versions of modules?

Tags: python, modules

The CPython implementation seems to have the same modules written both in C (e.g., [`datetime` in `.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_datetimemodule.c)) and also in .py for the same module (e.g., [`datetime` in `.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/datetime.py)).

My question is which version is used when I use datetime in my .py file when using the CPython interpreter? And why are there two module versions in the first place?

Comment: [The C modules only work with implementations like CPython. The pure-Python modules will work with *any* implementation of Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69636704)

Comment: [As CPython is the reference implementation, they are defining the semantics of how each module should work in other implementations.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69636704)

Comment: As an aside, the fact that the reference implementation of Python is available in both C and python (under a permissive license) is all kinds of awesome.

Comment: It kind of makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are two modules in the standard lib with the same name, what often has happened is that the original module was written in Python.  That's because it is a lot easier to prototype and get it working quickly than in lower-level languages.

Later, once a reasonable design has been found and bugs fixed etc, performance may become a focus.  It's a good time to write the slow parts in Cython or the C API and speed them up through compilation to machine code.  Typically the additions are placed in a `_module.so` or DLL and imported from within the original `module.py`.

This avoids the work of prototyping/writing the entire thing in the C API, which is quite tedious.

Answer (score 3):

C code is real code, python is interface code.

The c code is the performant code, while the python is for python runtime to correctly handle call sites.

Also use the c code Version to get the most performance.